# jquery get value of next instance of class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use jQuery to get the value of the divs with the classes of `more_details_con`, `more_details_desc` and `more_details_res` and when `edit_entry` is clicked but I don't think I am traversing the DOM correctly because the alert just says undefined.

The HTML

```
<div class="details">
    <span class="id">1234</span>
    <span class="contact">account name</span>
</div>

<div class = "more_details">
    <div class = "more_details_btns">
        <div class="go_account">Go to Account</div>
        <div class="edit_entry">Edit</div>
        <div class="delete_entry">Delete</div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="more_details_title">Contact:</div>
        <div class="more_details_con">Contact name</div>
        <p class="clear"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="more_details_title">Description:</div>
        <div class="more_details_desc">Actual Description</div>
        <p class="clear">
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="more_details_title">Resolution:</div>
        <div class="more_details_res">Actual Resolution</div>
        <p class="clear">
    </div>
</div>
```

The jQuery I've tried

```
$("#results").on("click", ".edit_entry", function() {
    var contact = $(this).next(".more_details_con").html();
    var desc = $(this).next(".more_details_desc").html();
    var res = $(this).next(".more_details_res").html();
    alert(contact+desc+res);
});
```

Comment: @tushar thanks but that only finds the first value I am looking for

Answer (score 4):

The issue is because the elements you're looking for are not siblings of the one which raised the event. You instead could use `closest()` to find the nearest common parent element, `.more_details`, and then `find()` to get the element you want. Try this:

```
$("#results").on("click", ".edit_entry", function() {
    var $parent = $(this).closest('.more_details');
    var contact = $parent.find(".more_details_con").text();
    var desc = $parent.find(".more_details_desc").text();
    var res = $parent.find(".more_details_res").text();

    console.log(contact, desc, res);
});
```

Comment: perfect, thanks.  I will accept when it allows me to.

Comment: No problem, glad to help